# ライブビュー受信時のmetadataの内容について

Tags: olympus-camerakit

`OLYCameraLiveViewListener` の以下のメソッドでライブビュー画像を処理する際に、同時に取得できるmetadataに格納されている情報について記載されているドキュメントはありませんでしょうか？
常にOrientation情報しか入っていないようなのですが、これで正常なのでしょうか？

```
void onUpdateLiveView (OLYCamera camera, byte[] data, Map< String, Object > metadata)
```

Olympus Camera Kit ver 1.1.1

宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

OPCサポートです。

ご質問ありがとうございます。
現在のところ`metadata`に格納されている情報は回転情報のみです。